# What is this thing in my Macbook Pro's headphone jack?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I got a Macbook Pro in January 2018.  Mostly it's as expected, however the laptop arrived with some sort of glass plug (or *something*) lodged in the headphone jack.  It's somewhere between amber and reddish in color and there doesn't seem to be any way to remove it from the jack (not that I've been able to find, anyways).  It looks like maybe it's supposed to light up or something, though as far as I can tell it doesn't and the only purpose it seems to serve is making it impossible to actually use the headphone jack.

Here are a couple of photos.  They're not the best, but hopefully they give an idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

[image]

What is this thing, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: It's not a 2017 MacBook Pro...so what model is it?  As far as what that looks like, it could be FOD  (foreign object debris).  Just pop it out.

Comment: On the back it says "Model A1398".

Comment: The _thing_ doesn't pop out.  It's made of smooth glass and fits snugly in the headphone jack.  It only protrudes by a millimeter (or two, tops).  There's no way to get a good purchase on it for yanking, even with tweezers.  It at least _seems_ like something put there deliberately.

Comment: @aroth This is not normal. I would suggest bringing it to an Apple store and have them open the computer up and pop it out.